# How to add 5 random numbers which are less than 10?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math, push

I've created two functions. One to create 5 random numbers to push them into an array. And another one to sum up the numbers. The random number generator is working and making an array perfectly. But the sum is not accurate. I'm unable to find where the problem is.

```js
//Generates 5 random numbers smaller than 10

function pushIntoArray() {
    let arr = [];
    let number;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        arr.push(number);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(pushIntoArray());

//Adds the numbers in arr
function sumNum(arr) {
    let total = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
let arr = pushIntoArray();
console.log(sumNum(arr));
```

Comment: The `sumNum` function is adding up all numbers in your array, and returning the result of that sum, so it is accurate in that regard. Can you explain why the result it not accurate?

Comment: How is the sum not accurate. When I call `pushIntoArray` I get `[ 1, 6, 10, 4, 9 ]` which then correctly sums to `30`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are logging a different set of array values and checking the sum of different set of array values.
I have changed your `console.log` statement.

```js
//Generates 5 random numbers smaller than 10

function pushIntoArray() {
    let arr = [];
    let number;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        arr.push(number);
    }
    return arr;
}

//Adds the numbers in arr
function sumNum(arr) {
    let total = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
let arr = pushIntoArray();
console.log(arr);
console.log(sumNum(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not performing the sum on the array that you logged in the console. What you are logging is

```
console.log(pushIntoArray()); // This is displayed in the console
```

But then you are generating a ney array by calling

```
let arr = pushIntoArray();
```

BUT you are performing the sum on the `arr` array not the one that is displayed in the console.

```
console.log(sumNum(arr)); // you did not console.log(arr)
```

The function works correctly, you are just calling it on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

the function is working correctly but you are logging a different array of random numbers and calculating the sum of a different array.

```js
//Generates 5 random numbers smaller than 10

function pushIntoArray() {
    let arr = [];
    let number;
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        arr.push(number);
    }
    return arr;
}
// this array is different (this is not passed to the sumNum function)
console.log(pushIntoArray());

//Adds the numbers in arr
function sumNum(arr) {
    let total = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total;
}
// this array is different
let arr = pushIntoArray();
console.log("sum of array:", arr)
console.log(sumNum(arr));
```